# SearchHandler xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin

I have Xamarin xaml proyect, in this a SearchHandler, in Android, it look very well, but on iOs the rows are very narrow and the content overlaps, the SearchHandler is a grid of two rows and two columns, the image occupies two rows in the first column, and there is other data in the second column, and data in row 0 and another at 1.
attach image  [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MblEy.png)
[ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMP6g.png)

How i can do with iOs?
Thank you

Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ArticuloSearchTemplate">
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       WidthRequest="80"
                       HeightRequest="80"
                    />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding ArtDescri}" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{Binding PreValor, StringFormat='{0:C}'}"
                       FontAttributes="None" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

```
 <ListView  x:Key="ArticuloSearchTemplateLista"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            RowHeight="120">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>


                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                Aspect="AspectFit"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="80"
                                HeightRequest="80" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Text="{Binding ArtDescri}" 
                                FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Text="{Binding PreValor, StringFormat='{0:C}'}"
                                FontAttributes="None" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


<controls:ArticulosSearchHandler Placeholder="Ingrese palabra clave"
                                      ShowsResults="True"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticuloSearchTemplateLista}"


                                      />
```

I change , but it does not display as the image you sent me, the data source is to List .
Should I change something?

Fill SearchHandler:

```
  <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <controls:ArticulosSearchHandler Placeholder="Ingrese palabra clave"
                                      ShowsResults="True"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticuloSearchTemplate}"
                                      SelectedItemNavigationTarget="{x:Type views:ArticulosDetalles}"
                                      BackgroundColor="White"
                                      TextColor="Black"
                                      />
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
 protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);
            try
            {
                ObservableCollection<ArticulosEntidades> observableCollection;
                var filteredItems = Estaticos._Articulos
                    .Where(m => m.ArtDescri.ToLower().Contains(newValue.ToLower()))
                    .ToList();
                observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<ArticulosEntidades>(filteredItems);

                if (observableCollection == null || observableCollection.Count == 0)
                    ItemsSource = null;
                else
                    ItemsSource = observableCollection;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
```

[ListView iOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48NA6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with setting `RowHeight` for ListView to check whehter it works .

Such as setting  `RowHeight="120"` as follow :

```
<ListView x:Name="searchResults"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            RowHeight="120">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*" />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Source="icon.png"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="80"
                            HeightRequest="80" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="row 0 column 1"
                            FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="row 1 column 1"
                            FontAttributes="None" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, but the result is diferent, I edit the question for add image and code [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48NA6.png)

Comment: @cristian That's because the `ViewModel` is different with my project . You can share the code of `ViewModel` binded for `ListView` , I will check that .

Comment: Code in Question, here is too long

Comment: @cristian Thanks for sharing . I will check that .

Comment: @cristian Hi , sorry for not found where problem is . Could you share a new created sample project here with this problem ? If so , I will reproduce this in my local site and check where problem is .